# mediaplayer streaming a chunked encoded mp3 stream outputs no sound on the droid x2

Tags: android, mp3, audio-streaming, android-mediaplayer, motorola-droid

I am connecting to a server that is streaming mp3 frames with a chunked transfer encoding over http 1.1. The android MediaPlayer api successfully plays this stream in 4 different phones I've tested it on, including the Droid X. However, on the Motorola Droid X2, it plays w/o error for approximately the correct duration of time (the isPlaying() call keeps returning true for the duration), however no sound comes out of the earphones, and no errors are outputted.

In addition, during this 'playback', the hardware volume controls manage the ringer volume, instead of the expected music volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Droid X2 does not like small chunks of data (via chunked transfer encoding). Single frame chunks ended being silent, and 16kb chunks resulted in stuttering. Increasing the size of the chunks resulted in better performance.